# For a given sequence of n numbers, find the substring with a maximum total sum with the lowest computational complexity as possible

Tags: c++, algorithm

Task:For a given sequence of n numbers, find the substring with a maximum total sum. I created I code in C++ which give correct answers. I would like to know is there any possibility to solve this task with lower computational complexity?
Example input:

```
20
8973
-4625
-2038
3405
-7004
-9853
-361
3294
4036
8767
1711
-3100
2139
-4993
-9572
3789
2472
-6170
5408
2200
```

output:

```
17808
```

My actual code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

typedef long long int lint;

int main()
{
    lint t = 0;
    cin >> t;
    vector<lint> Ar;
    bool st = false;
    for (lint i = 0; i < t; i++)
    {
        lint n = 0;
        cin >> n;
        if (st == true)Ar.push_back(n);
        else if (n>0 && st == false)
        {
            Ar.push_back(n);
            st = true;
        }

    }
    if (Ar.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << "0" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        vector<lint> Adding;
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < Ar.size(); i++)
        {
            if (Ar[i] > 0)
            {
                Adding.push_back(i);
            }
        }



        vector<lint> D;
        for (std::size_t j = 0; j < Adding.size(); j++)
        {
            lint s = 0;

            for (std::size_t i = Adding[j]; i < Ar.size(); i++)
            {


                if (Ar[i] > 0)
                {
                    s += Ar[i];
                    D.push_back(s);
                }
                else
                {
                    s += Ar[i];
                }
            }

        }

        vector<lint>::const_iterator it2;
        // Find max element in the vector
        it2 = max_element(D.begin(), D.end());
        cout << *it2 << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?

Comment: lower complexity @amit

Comment: Do you expect us to analyse your C++ code? Since computational complexity is about the algorithm and not the code, why don't you describe the algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best computational complexity to solve this task is linear. Your code on the other hand is not linear and therefor the answer to your question is - yes it is possible to solve the problem with better complexity.

The problem you are solving is known as [Maximum subarray problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) and is quite famous.

Answer (score 1):

It looks that you went straight into writing code.

The first step would be to think about the problem.

The optimal sequence might include the first number 20. If you examine the numbers from the start, where might the sequence end with an optimal result if it starts with 20? And at which point could you say that any longer sequence that is optimal cannot contain the number 20?

If you look at the sequence and examine it one by one, you will see that 20+8973 might be optimal. Up to 3405 is not optimal but might be the start of an optimal sequence. But with the -9853 it is obvious that an optimal sequence other than 20+8973 must start with the 3294 or later. (Ask yourself why, then turn it into an algorithm).